# How to implement a custom pipe which replaces a dot with a comma?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I have a number with decimal points like --> 1.33

I want to convert the this value that instead a dot a comma is shown.

I tried that with a custom pipe but that didn´t work.

```
{{getMyValue() | number:'1.2-2' | commaConvert}}
```

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({name: 'commaConvert'})
export class CommaConvertPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: number) {
        return value+"".replace(".", ",")
    }
}
```

I have also tried to use only the commaConvert pipe.

Comment: Could you clarify *"doesn't work"*? Also note that the output of DecimalPipe#transform and therefore the input of CommaConvertPipe#transform is string, not number.

Comment: You were right. The problem was that the value from the DecimalPipe was a string and not a number.

Comment: `value+"".replace(".", ",")` means you only replace in `""`.

Answer (score -1):

Please, edit in transform return

```js
return value.toString().replace(".", ",")
```